# Data abstraction from unstructured pdf analysis, what tools and library should i go through?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I want to abstract data from unstructured **invoices** pdf, need a good machine learning analysis tool for it, or even good direction to lean would also be helpful.

Comment: What type of analysis do you want to make on invoice pdf?

Comment: @AILearning, invoice type might vary widely from client to client, our aim is to understand each and every entry written in the invoice, match the total and every field total with our expected fare